# Background image in Styles.css appearing in every react router pages

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-router

A folder with pages was created, inside every page for using with react router, then when adding a background one of them in styles.css, every single page will display that same background.

I assigned a background image in this way:

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  background-image: url("../../assets/images/Brandnewlaptop.jpg"); 
  background-size: cover; 
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

I wanted to place that image in just that page, in specify different image background in the remaining pages, but it's instead this make all of them get the "Bradnewlaptop" background.

Comment: Can you [edit] the post to include a more complete and relevant [mcve] of the React and `react-router` code you are working with?

Answer (score 0):

When writing a program in react you set a root element to be replaced by your code, but since root is a child of body, the properties you give to body will be shown no matter what you set root to be. What you can do is you can give the background image to the top element in the components you want to have the background